# Entering pdb disables subsequent set_trace() calls

Tags: python, signals, pdb

I enter the `pdb` debugger, and then interactively call a function. The function has a `set_trace()` call inside it, and I expect the debugger to stop there. Unfortunately, the call is ignored, as if the subsequent debugger call wasn't even there. Here's the code:

```
import pdb

def f():
    print('enter')
    pdb.set_trace()
    print('exit')

pdb.set_trace()
```

Here's the output. Note that `set_trace()` between "enter" and "exit" is never invoked.

```
--Return--
> /home/chucknorris/test2.py(8)<module>()->None
-> pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) f()
enter
exit
(Pdb)
```

How can I trigger subsequent calls to `set_trace()` when calling a function interactively from the debugger?

Comment: I guess I'm confused with what you're trying to do. With `pdb.set_trace()`, you enter the debugger. After that, you have to set a [break point](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands).

Comment: I enter the debugger, and then interactively call a function. The function has a `set_trace()` call inside it, and I expect the debugger to stop there. Unfortunately, the call is ignored, as if `set_trace()` wasn't even there.

Comment: @rkesh, I shortened the question to just the essentials, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I think the answer is that subsequent calls to `set_trace` don't trigger a break point (the documentation isn't very explicit on this and nor is the pdb.py source code).  You are already in the debugger once you enter it the first time, so from then on, you have to use break points.  It may be possible to define your own class that inherits from pdb.Pdb and adds this extra functionality (i.e., overrides the default set_trace method).  I don't have time to research that at the moment, but sounds interesting.